# How is new object instantiation handled in case of Datasets?

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark

I have to following scenario

```
 case class A(name:String)
 class Eq { def isMe(s:String) = s == "ME" }
 val a = List(A("ME")).toDS
 a.filter(l => new Eq().isMe(l.name))
```

Does this create a new object `Eq` every time for each data point on each executor ?

Comment: Yes, for each record there will be an `Eq` instantiated. Why don't you just define your function inside `filter`? Or use an `object` instead which you can broadcast

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nice one! I didn't know there is a different filter method for a typed dataset.
In order to answer your question, I will do some deep dive into Spark internals.

`filter` on a typed Dtaset has the following signature:

```
def filter(func: T => Boolean): Dataset[T]
```

Note that `func` is parameterized with `T`, hence Spark needs to deserialize both your object `A` along with the function.

```
TypedFilter Main$$$Lambda$, class A, [StructField(name,StringType,true)], newInstance(class A)
```

where `Main$$$Lambda$` is a randomly generated function name

During optimization phase it might be eliminated by the [EliminateSerialization](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/branch-2.4/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/optimizer/objects.scala#L52) rule if the following condition is met:

> `ds.map(...).filter(...)` can be optimized by this rule to save extra deserialization, but `ds.map(...).as[AnotherType].filter(...)` can not be optimized.

If the rule is applicable `TypedFilter` is [replaced](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/branch-2.4/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/plans/logical/object.scala#L212) by [`Filter`](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/branch-2.4/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/plans/logical/basicLogicalOperators.scala#L128).

The catch here is a Filter's `condition`. In fact, it is another special expression named [Invoke](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/branch-2.4/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/expressions/objects/objects.scala#L303) where:
`targetObject` is the filter function `Main$$$Lambda$`
`functionName` is `apply` since it is a regular Scala function.

Spark eventually runs in one of these two modes - `generate code` or `interpreter`. Let's concentrate on the first one as it is the default.

Here is a simplified stack trace of the methods invocation that will generate the code

```
SparkPlan.execute 
  //https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/03e30063127fd71bef8a14553381e805fe5b6679/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/WholeStageCodegenExec.scala#L596
  -> WholeStageCodegenExec.execute 
   [child: Filter]
    -> child.execute
       [condition Invoke]
     -> Invoke.genCode 
          //https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/branch-2.4/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/expressions/objects/objects.scala#L345  
          -> doGenCode
```

Simplified code after generation phase:

```
final class GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage1 extends BufferedRowIterator {
  private Object[] references;
  private scala.collection.Iterator input;
  private UnsafeRowWriter writer = new UnsafeRowWriter();

  public GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage1(Object[] references) {
    this.references = references;
  }

  public void init(Iterator inputs) {
    this.inputs = inputs;
  }

  protected void processNext() throws IOException {
    while (input.hasNext() && !stopEarly()) {
      InternalRow row = input.next();
      do {
        //Create A object
        UTF8String value = row.getUTF8String(0));
        A a = new A(value.toString)

        //Filter by A's value
        result = (scala.Function1) references[0].apply(a);

        if (!result) continue;

        writer.write(0, value)
        append((writer.getRow());

      }
      if (shouldStop()) return;
    }
  }
}
```

We can see that projection is constructed with an array of objects passed in references variable. But where and how many times the references variable is instantiated?
It is created during WholeStageCodegenExec and instantiated only once per [partition](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/03e30063127fd71bef8a14553381e805fe5b6679/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/WholeStageCodegenExec.scala#L719).

And this leads us to the answer that, however, `filter` function will be created only **once per partition** and not per data point, the `Eq` and `A` classes will be created **per data point**.

If you are curious about where it has been added to the code context:
It happens [here](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/03e30063127fd71bef8a14553381e805fe5b6679/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/expressions/literals.scala#L342)
where `javaType` is `scala.function1` . 
and `value` is the implementation - `Main$$$Lambda$`